# Encountering ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' although # All requested packages already installed

Tags: python, matplotlib, conda

I cannot import matplotlib in my .py file although i have already installed matplotlib which can be proved by powershell showed

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

I thought it was the mistake of having multi python versions in my computer.
So i entered

```
py -0
```

to check whether it is the situation. But powershell showed

```
Installed Pythons found by C:\WINDOWS\py.exe Launcher for Windows
 -3.9-64 *
```

So it is not due to multi python versions.

Can anyone help and explain please? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @ken lee, looks like `matplotlib` was installed to a different *virtual environment* than you are currently working in. This sometimes happens when you accidentally install packages to the "base" environment although you intended to install it to your working environment perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. How can i check it? Thanks.

Comment: how do you use Python? if it is in the command line, you may note a name in brackets before the command line, e.g. `(myenv)>`. If you don't see this, you are in the base or root environment. If you use the Anaconda navigator, you need to activate you environments first. Navigate to the environments and klick the play button. If there is only the root environment, create a new one and install the packages you want